# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound when I run my RSpec Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In a view/page, I trigger a jQuery post on a field change (no form submit) to update a date field in a database table. This seems to work all fine and dandy in my dev server, but when I run this test, I get an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFounderror, even though the counts before/after this statement return a 1, and I can see in FireFox that it is finding the first row and filling the date in.

In the test log, I see that all data is being deleted from the Order Line just prior to the object instantiation, which is what is causing this error but I dont see that happening to my other tests. This is driving me crazy, and any help is appreciated!

**ERROR**

```
Failures:

  1) Order Pages - WWhen a need by date is updated should update the line with the correct date
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find OrderLine with id=1
```

**RSPEC**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Order Pages - " do

  subject { page }

  before do
    create_order_and_sign_in_user 
  end

  def visit_a_order
    @order = @user.order.first
    visit order_lines_path(@order)
  end

  describe "When a need by date is updated" do

    it "should update the line with the correct date", js: true do
      visit_a_order  
         puts "Order lines count 1 - #{@order.lines.count}" // is 1 
      fill_in "needby_date", :with => "09/18/2014"
        puts "Order lines count 2 - #{@order.lines.count}" // is 1         
    end

  end  

end
```

**RSPEC HELPERS**

```
module OrderHelper

  def create_order_and_sign_in_user

     @user = create(:user)
     @order = create(:order, user: @user)
     @order_line = @order.order_line.create(description: "Order 1, Line 1")

     sign_in @user

  end

end

include ApplicationHelper

  def sign_in(user)
   visit new_user_session_path
   fill_in "Email", with: user.email
   fill_in "Password", with: user.password
   click_button "Sign in"
  end

  def fixture_file_path(file_name)
   File.join(fixture_path, file_name)
  end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
  def update_needby_date

    puts "Got to 1 - #{params[:order_line_id]}"
    @order_line = OrderLine.find(params[:order_line_id]) //Fails here with an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error
    puts "Got to 2 - #{params[:order_line_id]}"
    @order_line.needby_date = Date::strptime(params[:needby_date], "%m/%d/%Y")
    @order_line.save!
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js   { render :nothing => true }
    end

  end
```

**TEST LOG**

```
   [1m[36m (5.1ms)[0m  [1mDELETE FROM "order_lines";[0m
   [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='sqlite_sequence';
   [1m[36m (4.0ms)[0m  [1mDELETE FROM sqlite_sequence where name = 'order_lines';[0m

  Started POST "/order_lines/1/update_needby_date" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-01 22:52:00 +0530
  Processing by OrderLinesController#update_needby_date as */*
    Parameters: {"needby_date"=>"09/18/2014", "order_line_id"=>"1"}
    [1m[35mOrderLine Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT "order_lines".* FROM "order_lines" WHERE "order_lines"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
**Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms**
```

Comment: Show your `def create_order_and_sign_in_user`.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I just added my helper classes here. I use factories from factory_girl.

Comment: Here's an interesting thing that I found. When I pause the execution right after I fill in the date field with sleep(inspection_time=5), and manually choose a date, the test seems to pass!

Answer (score 0):

I guess all that was needed was a tab-out from the field. So I ended up filling in another field on the same page, and that let this test pass.

```
  describe "When a need by date is updated" do

     it "should update the line with the correct date", js: true do
      visit_a_order  
      fill_in "needby_date", :with => "09/18/2014"
      fill_in "line_description", :with => "Sample line!"
     end

  end
```